# Search Dexie table for a key in an array

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

If I have the following record in an indexedDB/Dexie table:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "foo",
  children: [{id: 12, bar: "b"},
             {id: 14, bar: "c"}]
}
```

each child id will be unique. That is to say only 1 record will have a child with a given id of 14.

1. how do I set up an index on children such that I can search for the record which contains a child with an id of 14?
2. how do I then most efficiently search for multiple records containing a child with a key in `anyOf([3, 7, 9])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IndexedDB allows MultiEntry indexing but only on simple arrays, and not arrays of objects. But you can workaround that by maintaining an array on the side with all the contained ids and index that property instead:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "foo",
  children: [{id: 12, bar: "b"},
             {id: 14, bar: "c"}],
  childrenIds: [12, 14]
}
```

```js
// Dexie schema:
const db = new Dexie("db");
db.version(1).stores({
  table: "++id, *childrenIds"
});
```

MultiEntry indexes works across Chromium, Firefox and Safari. IE11 does not support it but the upcoming Chromium-based Edge browser will.

**Alternate Approach**

Another approach is to design your tables in a relational way:

```js
const db = new Dexie("relDB");
db.version(1).stores({
  parents: "++id",
  children: "++id, parentId"
});
```

Parent objects:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "foo",
}
```

Child objects:

```
{id: 12, bar: "b", parentId: 1}
{id: 14, bar: "c", parentId: 1}
```

Then, to retrieve a parent based on a set of child ids [12, 14], use an anyOf() query on the children table:

```js
const children = await db.children.where('id').anyOf([12, 14]).toArray();
const parentIds = new Set(children.map(child => child.parentId));
const parents = await db.parents.bulkGet([...parentIds]);
```

**Conclusion**

I've presented two optional approaches that would both be efficient solutions for you question. The first option is to add a simple array of child IDs and index that using MultiEntry index, The other option is to put the children in a separate table. If you'd go for the second option, you might also have some help from using the [dexie-relationships](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dexie-relationships) addon to query children with parents included, or parents with children included.

*Note*

Reason I was indexing `parentId` on children was that it's a good practice to do that in relational schemas, in order to be able to query all children for a certain parent (which is not examplified here).

Answer (score 1):

Consider redundantly storing the parent data in the child objects. E.g. an object in your table would look like:

```
{
  "parent" : {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo",
  },
  "id": 12,
  "bar": "a"
}
```

You could then create an index on id. Or, because child id is the object key, you do not actually need to create an index, you can query against the key path of the object store.

However, you cannot do `IN` style queries. Because IN is essentially shorthand for `id = 1 or id = 2 or id = 3`, which is a union, which you cannot do in indexedDB. At least not efficiently. What you would need to do in this case is create 3 queries, one for each one, each one against the same index (or keypath of the object store), and then merge the results together into an array.

Comment: This approach works, but would use normal index, not multiEntry indexes. Also depending on the other use cases, I would rather recommend a relational approach (referrals between chilren and parent tables) as it would cover more use cases (such as querying parents first and then also include the children for those parents).

Also, IN style queries can be done quite efficient in indexedDB. For example, the new bulkGet() method in Dexie3 will do parallell queries to all given keys, which is a rather fast approach to get all the answers quick. anyOf() still does is serially but can be optimized.

Comment: @DavidFahlander that is great to hear regarding bulkGet, however, I think my point still stands, bulkGet is still doing multiple queries instead of a single one. no matter how you spin that, that is suboptimal.

Comment: You may be true about efficiency, I have no numbers yet, but I'm resonating like this: The cost of idb calls are pretty much round-trips plus the physical lookups, traversing and data processing within leveldb internally. But any db engine, including sql engines will need to do one lookup per key from the IN-query the exact same way under the hood (well it might be lucky and find all in same page though... so almost true) And roundtrip cost is eliminated by sending queries at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like:

1. only [Indexable Types](https://dexie.org/docs/Indexable-Type) can be used in multientry indexes
2. [Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/indexeddbarraysandmultientrysupport/#indexeddbarraysandmultientrysupport) still doesn't support the indexed-db standard for multientry keys!!! Frankly ridiculous.
3. Allowing the behavior described in the original question [has been suggested](https://github.com/w3c/IndexedDB/issues/35)